# Program to find Word Length Statistics

Tags: c

I am expected to make a program to calculate and display statistics about the length of words in a text file. I have been provided the following file

```
int readFile(const char fName[], char textStr[]){
    FILE *fPtr;
    char ch;
    int size = 0;

    if ((fPtr = fopen(fName, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to open %s: ", fName);
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fPtr)) != EOF) {
        if (size >= MAX_FILE - 1)
            break;
        textStr[size++] = ch;
    }

    textStr[size] = '\0';

    return size;
}
```

I was able to verify that I can access the file using the following code

```
int main() {
    char str[MAX_FILE];
    int len = readFile("test.txt", str);
    if (len == -1) {
        printf("An error occurred\n");
    } else {
        printf("file read");
    }
}
```

File `test.txt` contains

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

What I want to do is to get the contents of `test.txt` and find the length of each word in it something like:-

```
1 letter words- 0
2 letter words - 0
3 letter words - 3
4 letter words -4
```

and so on...

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Please edit the question, and show an example of the file contents, and what you are expecting the output to be.

Comment: what is the actual problem you are facing (compiler error, unexpected output, ...)?

Comment: I imagine textStr is passed as an argument to that function? If so, it's a pointer and you don't have to return the string. After your function terminates, the caller should have the array locally and you can access the contents of it.

Comment: One bug: `ch` needs to be an int, not a char: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: What are your plans?  What have you tried?  How are you going to record the length of each word?  How are you going to count the number of words of each length?  You really need to show us what you've tried and where you're having problems.  You've made a reasonable start with the first version of `main()`.  Now *you* need to write the next part of the code, presumbly scanning the string returned by `readFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow new contributor, I'm going to give you a break and try to answer the question you didn't ask. ;)

I believe the question is "how to proceed".  This is going to be a **long answer** as I will try be very detailed since you seem to be a newbie.  Hopefully this will help you or maybe someone else.

The trick is to take a word problem and convert it into a mathematical solution.  The best way to do this is to write "pseudocode".  (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) for more information, if you need to.)  I'm going to give you some pseudocode at the end, but since this appears to be a homework assignment, please try to write your own pseudocode first.  If you read the pseudocode and it still doesn't help, I can post my solution later.  (I'm not a great programmer so it might not be the *best* program.  And it took way overlong to come up with it.)

First things first:  There appears to be a typo in the code you posted.  In the source code you were provided, the problem is the `return 1` statement if the file isn't found.  That should be `return -1`, because what would happen if you had a test file that had exactly 1 letter?  The code wouldn't work correctly.

Now, to first convert the word problem you were given:  You need to have an array of word counts to keep track of 1-letter, 2-letter, etc. words.  Now according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English) the longest word in the English dictionary is 45 letters.  So, in theory, you would need to have an array of 45 elements of `wordCounts`.  You can shorten this as required.

Now to process your `str` variable, you need a `while` statement to go through one character at a time.  Since the characters in the string go from element 0 through one less that the `len` variable, you need to code the `while` accordingly.

Within that `while`, you need *another* `while`.  This while needs to count up the `wordLength` one character at a time, until you see a blank or the trailing '/0' character of `str`.  To do this, you initialize the wordLength to zero right before the second while.  Then add 1 to the wordLength for each character you count and increment your `subscript`.

At the end of this inner `while` you need to accumulate your wordCounts.  Keep in mind that your 1-letter words are going to be accumulated into element 0 of your array.  So you need to adjust the `wordLength - 1` array element.  After that you need to increment your subscript you are using to go through your `str`, one character at a time.

At the end, you need to print out the wordCounts array values.  Since most of the word lengths will have a value of zero, I wouldn't print these.  Unless you set the maximum length of the wordCounts array to something like 10, instead of 45.  You want a `for` loop to go through your wordCounts array, and do something like this:  `printf("%2d letter words = %d", ..., ...);`.  Keep in mind your 1-letter words are going to be in element 0;

That is a *very detailed* version of a word problem that is the solution to the problem of "count the number of words that the phrase has from 1-letter words to **x**-letter words".

Here is the pseudocode I came up with, after coding my solution.  It is a little more detailed than normal pseudocode would be.  (Personally, I abbreviate all variable names and use Pascal case, but that's just me.)

Declare a numeric array of `wordCounts` and a `subscript`.

`For` each element of wordCounts, zero out the number of words or the code won't work right.

Reinitialize `subscript` to zero.

As long as (`while`) the subscript is less than the `len`, continue.

Initialize the `wordLength` to zero.

As long as the `str[subscript]` is not a blank or a null character, add 1 to the wordLength.

Increment the subscript.

After both `while` statements are complete print out the array of wordLengths, as described above.

Your done!

Now I could post the actual code that could be used to come up with this pseudocode, but it would be better if you came up with it yourself.  If you try but have a bug in your code, post a new question, and I'll try to check back to answer it.  Hope this helps you or someone else.